# How to resolve infinite loop error in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Modal bootstrap from reactjs in which onLoad i am calling function captchGen()and further I was trying to store validation inside H2 tag

i am getting infinite loop error: ×
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
const Modals = (props) => {
const [validation , setValidation] = useState("");
const [result , setResult] = useState(0);
const [inputValue , setInput] = useState("");

const captchGen = () => {
    const data1 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
    const data2 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
    const str = ` Enter ${data1} + ${data2} `
    const sum = data1+data2
    setValidation(str);
    setResult(sum)
}

const handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
}


const captchValidation = () => {
    const x = result;
    const y = inputValue;
    if ( x === y) {
         alert("success")
    }
    else {
         alert("fail")
    }
}

  return (
    <Modal {...props} onLoad={captchGen()} size="sm" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Captcha</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
         <input type = "text" placeHolder = "Enter the number" onChange = { e => handleInput(e)}></input>
                <button onClick = {captchValidation} >Validate</button>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Modals;
```

here is modal code

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Button variant="dark"
      onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}
    >Subscribe</Button>
    <Modals
      show={modalShow}
      onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}

    />
  )
}
```

Comment: onLoad = {captchGen()}  // change this to onLoad = {captchGen}

Comment: I am not getting this ` Enter ${data1} + ${data2} ` inside H2 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are executing the `captchGen` function rather than passing the reference to it.

```
    const Modals = (props) => {

    const [validation , setValidation] = useState("");
    const [result , setResult] = useState(0);

    const captchGen = () => {
        const data1 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
        const data2 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
        const str = ` Enter ${data1} + ${data2} `
        const sum = data1+data2
        setValidation(str);
        setResult(sum);
    }


    return (
            <Modal
                {...props}
                onLoad = {captchGen}
                size="sm"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        Captcha
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <h2>{validation}</h2> 
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                    <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
    );
};

export default Modals;
```

Comment: Hi @Sreeram Padmanabhan <h2>{validation}</h2> is not rendering and i think captchGen is also not rendering because when i console both validation itsblank and for result its 0 only

Comment: Is  there any other property so that i can call?

Comment: If you are using Modal from react-bootstrap, the documentation tells me there is nothing called onLoad. But I can see an `onEnter`

Comment: Hi @Sreeram Padmanabhan Thankyou so much now its working and i had made the changes to my question everytime alert is showing fail only can you please look into this

Comment: <input type = "text" placeHolder = "Enter the number" onChange = { e => handleInput(e)} value={inputValue}></input>

Comment: You are comparing a string to an interger. Try x == y. Or try setting sum as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your modal has an `onLoad` prop which calls `captchGen()`.

`captchGen()` changes your state which re-renders your component and restarts the loop.

Change `onLoad={captchGen()}` to `onLoad={captchGen}` to pass your function to `onLoad` instead of calling it directly.

Comment: Hi @Luze if i just pass onLoad={captchGen} then console.log is not printing anything and i am trying to render this <h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: validation}} ></h2>